# Processing dynamic PHP variable output with domPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I've been working on a script where the I should create a PDF from a dynamically created data from a page. After some research, I've decided to use domPDF. I currently use CodeIgniter as my framework so I came up with this [tutorial](http://imron02.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/create-pdf-in-codeigniter-part-ii/). So from this tutorial, I got the following set of codes for the controller.

Controller: dompdf_test.php -  This will be used for generating the actual PDF based on the loaded view.

```
class Dompdf_test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {   
        // Load all views as normal
        $this->load->view('summary/index');
        // Get output html
        $html = $this->output->get_output();

        // Load library
        $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');

        // Convert to PDF
        $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
        $this->dompdf->render();
        $this->dompdf->stream("SavedData.pdf");
    }
}
```

Controller: dompdf_view.php - This is just the page to be accessed that will be converted to PDF

```
class Dompdf_view extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('summary/index');
    }
}
```

Library: dompdf_gen.php - Located at application/libraries

```
class Dompdf_gen {

    public function __construct() {

        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php'; //this is where the whole dompdf plugin is located

        $pdf = new DOMPDF();
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->dompdf = $pdf;
    }
}
```

So here it goes: the page that I want to convert to PDF produces data that are manipulated by a user. Generated data are not from database but based on what's selected by a user. For instance, user selected Female as the gender. That "Female" word will be added to a summary tab (on the same page). All data in summary tab will be included on the pdf file. I thought of passing those data to another php file since that page includes a lot of unrelated data for pdf saving and domPDF does not support some CSS syntax (if my understanding was right). Data passed at that said file will be the basis of a simple PDF template tables.

Now here's the problem. I used this very simple [code](http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=php_passing_variables.php#post) on passing of data:

View: summary/sourceData.php 
- sample page where I should input the data. All entered data will be passed in summary/index view.

```
<form method="post" action="http://siteURL/dompdf_view"> //dompdf_view is simply the summary/index page
 <input type="text" name="name0" placeholder="Add text"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="name1" placeholder="Add text"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="name2" placeholder="Add text"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="name3" placeholder="Add text"/><br/> 
 <input type="text" name="name4" placeholder="Add text"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pass Variable"/>

</form>
```

summary/index.php - This is where the data is passed.

```
 <?php 

$name0 = isset($_POST['name0']) ? $_POST['name0'] : "";
$name1 = isset($_POST['name1']) ? $_POST['name1'] : "";
$name2 = isset($_POST['name2']) ? $_POST['name2'] : "";
$name3 = isset($_POST['name3']) ? $_POST['name3'] : "";
$name4 = isset($_POST['name4']) ? $_POST['name4'] : "";

    echo $name0.'<br/><br/>'; 
    echo $name1.'<br/><br/>'; 
    echo $name2.'<br/><br/>'; 
    echo $name3.'<br/><br/>'; 
    echo $name4.'<br/><br/>';

    ?>

    <a href="<http://siteURL/dompdf_test>">Save as PDF</a>
```

Data from summary/sourceData.php are passed to summary/index.php but when I try to save summary/index.php to pdf, it saves but does not get any data. It's just a BLANK PDF document except for the word Save as PDF.

I researched and tried adding  but still no luck.

Can't domPDF read php echo files? If not, how?

I have no idea yet how I will be able to save those data to pdf. Or, is there another way to pass those data?

NOTE: Code above is working if the page is a static one. But when I add dynamic data, it does not read the PHP results from that page inside the PDF file.

Any help/advices will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code in question so it can be looked over, it looks like your using the array incorrectly on line number 8.

Comment: Hi @Skewled, my apologies. I edited the question.

Comment: <a href="<dompdf process url here>">Save as PDF</a> where is the code for this? is action.php processing the data or are you passing the data from action.php to a new page? I don't see the code where your working with domPDF to create the actual pdf...

Comment: @Skewled, I updated my question and included all the codes I have here. :)

Comment: Because the user-submitted values are submitted to the current page and not persisted on the back end dompdf has no way of seeing the rendered HTML. You'll need to pass the values to the server again and re-render the HTML before giving it to dompdf.

Comment: Hi @BrianS, I just realized it too. I am currently working on passing the values again and re-rendering the HTML. Thanks! :) Great work on domPDF btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We came up with a solution to my problem. Data submitted was not passed to the controller that's why it's blank. What we did was, we submitted the data through input post and added the following in the controller:

```
$html = $this->load->view('summary/index', $data, true);
```

Thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are generating your pdf by clicking the link "Save as PDF" you trigger a new request from the view summary/index view without any POST parameters.
Then your controller to that is generating the pdf is called server side and renders the summary index view for pdf generation, but now without any post parameters. That is why your pdf is empty.
You can replace

```
<a href="<http://siteURL/dompdf_test>">Save as PDF</a>
```

with:

```
  if($_POST['submit']!='Save as PDF'){
    ?>
      <form method="post" action="http://siteURL/dompdf_test"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="name0" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name0,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8')?>"/><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name1,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8')?>" /><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name2,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8')?>"/><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="name3" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name3,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8')?>"/><br/> 
        <input type="hidden" name="name4" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name4,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8')?>"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save as PDF"/>
      </form>
    <?php
  }
```

Comment: Hi, @AthanasiusKirchner. Thanks for your help. I tried your code but still PDF is blank. Even if I add a static string, it's not added to the PDF. In a way, I agree with what you said that my summary/index view is not getting those POST parameters that's why it's blank. If that's the case, any idea on how to render that view together with the POST params?

Comment: I am not that familiar with this library(domPDF), but https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/ stands something like "not particularly tolerant to poorly-formed HTML". Try to that `$html = '<html><head></head><body><h1>Thats a Test</h1></body></html>';` in your controller instead of using the rendered view used to check if thats the problem.

Comment: Yes. That $html will surely work if the page is static. But once it became dynamic, like having POST params, that's my dilemma for now. Though I am currently working on a solution. Thanks, @AthanasiusKirchner :)

Answer (score 0):

this should give you a hint on how dompdf works.

```
        //File when you gererate $html
        $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
        require_once($dir.'/file_to_generate_html_from_php.php');  
        // Load the dompdf files  
        require_once($dir.'/include/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');  

        $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); // Create new instance of dompdf  
        $dompdf->load_html($html); // Load the html  
        $dompdf->render(); // Parse the html, convert to PDF  
        $pdf_content = $dompdf->output(); // Put contents of pdf into variable for later
```

**file_to_generate_html_from_php.php** - Should look something like this.

```
$html = '
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <html lang="sv">
</head>
<body>';
$html .='<h2>Report</h2>';
$html .='
</body>
</html>';
```

You can also run php code to generate $html inside **file_to_generate_html_from_php.php**

```
$SQLQUERY= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column = '$variable'") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $SQLQUERY)) {
                                                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                                                if(empty($row['Column'])){
                                                $html .= '<p>No results!</p>';
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                $html .= '<pre>Yes we found this: '.$row['Column'].'</pre>';
                                                }
                                        }
```

Comment: Hi @hedqvist, I can generate a pdf on my current code almost similar to yours. Though my problem is, the data that needs to be in the PDF are dynamic based on selected and inputs and all are not based on sql data. Just in case, do you know how to use inline PHP in dompdf? I researched but cant find any reliable docs.

Comment: you can use something like if(isset($variable)){echo $html .= "More html to enter to html variable if $variable is set."}