# Issue on echoing Post Data in a String Varaible

Tags: php

Trying to export a Content received from a POST function I have :

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['html']))
  {
    $content = $_POST['html'];

  }

require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
$codigo= '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html> 
';
$codigo = utf8_decode($codigo);
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($codigo);
ini_set("memory_limit","32M");
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("ejemplo.pdf");
```

now I need to export the  `$content = $_POST['html'];` inside the `$codigo` string I tried these things as:

```
$codigo= '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
       '.echo $content; .'
</body>
</html>';
```

and

```
$codigo= '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
       '. $content .'
</body>
</html>';
```

but I am getting syntax error. Can you please let me know how I can insert the POST data into that content?

Thanks

Comment: What error you're getting?

Comment: The last attempt certainly does _not_ produce a _syntax_ error.

Comment: Hi hindmost, at first case: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\wamp\www\PDF4\pdf.php on line 14

Comment: change a '.$content.' to '".$content.".

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$codigo= "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   {$content}
 </body>
</html>";
```

Comment: You've forgot closing double-quote

Comment: This code will return the same output that the second attempt

Answer (score 0):

I think we had the same dilemma. I was working on passing values from POST. What's the output of your PDF, is it blank? You may want to check this: [Processing dynamic PHP variable output with domPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098590/processing-dynamic-php-variable-output-with-dompdf/23210208#23210208)